# How to add 'Welcome {username}' in blocks with Drupal 7

Tags: blocks

I am replacing a drupal 6 website by a drupal 7 one with the same content.
On that Drupal 6 website there is a block that comes visible when you're logged in. 
As  heading it shows the message 'Welcome {username}' in that block.

I'm looking for a way to do that in Drupal 7, i tried to do this with the module 'Token' but i doesn't work. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Here is a blog post about that: http://is.gd/j2q0Uu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either in a block or in a custom module that adds a block, add the following code:

```
if (user_is_logged_in() == TRUE) {
    global $user;

    print "Welcome " . $user->name;
}
else {
    print "Please log in.";
}
```

[This](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/user/7) is more useful if you want CURRENT user information.  Possibly [this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/) as well for the `user_is_logged_in` function.

Comment: This worked fine. I found the solution by reading the first answer below this.
However, i didn't know about the module for php content that is standard delivered with Drupal, so i had to search a bit further.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: No need for the call to user_is_logged_in() as that is just doing what you are already going by using the $user global variable.
Just check $user->uid as per my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this in a module (recommended as opposed to adding php code to a block, which would then not be in version control), then you can do this:

(in this case, all this code would go in a custom module named userwelcome.)

```php
/**
 * @file
 * Adds a block that welcomes users when they log in.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function userwelcome_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'userwelcome_welcome_block' => array(
      'variables' => array('user' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function userwelcome_block_info() {
  // This example comes from node.module.
  $blocks['welcome'] = array(
    'info' => t('User welcome'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_USER,
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function userwelcome_block_view($delta = '') {
  global $user;
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'welcome':
      // Don't show for anonymous users.
      if ($user->uid) {
        $block['subject'] = '';
        $block['content'] = array(
          '#theme' => 'userwelcome_welcome_block',
          '#user' => $user,
        );
      }
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * Theme the user welcome block for a given user.
 */
function theme_userwelcome_welcome_block($variables) {
  $user = $variables['user'];
  $output = t('Welcome !username', array('!username' => theme('username', array('account' => $user))));
  return $output;
}
```

If you then wanted to override the themeing of this block in a theme you would do this (in your template.php file of your theme):

```
/**
 * Theme the userwelcome block.
 */
function THEMENAME_userwelcome_welcome_block(&$variables) {
  // Return the output of the block here.
}
```

Note that because this is a custom module you could also just update the theme funciton in the module directly.

If you don't want to use a custom module you can create a custom block with php code and add this:

```
global $user;
// Only for logged in users.
if ($user->uid) {
  print 'Welcome ' . theme('username', array('account' => $user));
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, though I'm a little unclear about the naming and location of each of the functions. Here are my assumptions - can you advise if I am correct? Assuming *theme* name is `theme_userwelcome`, should function `theme_userwelcome_welcome_block` be placed in the *theme* not the `userwelcome` module. Presumably, `userwelcome_theme` function should actually be called `userwelcome_theme_theme` (yes 2 theme words as name of the theme replaces `hook`) & placed in the theme `theme_userwelcome`. functions `userwelcome_block_view` and `userwelcome_block_info` remain in `userwelcome`.

Comment: I have updated the answer with this info: All this code goes an a module named userwelcome. If you wanted to override the themeing of the block from a theme you would use THEMENAME_userwelcome_welcome_block(&$variables)

Answer (score 5):

Use views module. Create new view > show users > block display. Add contextual filter > provide default argument > user ID from logged in user. Configure fields (you can rewrite results) to include whatever text/tokens or user profile fields you wish. Save and add block to region.

Done with one module and no code.

-lunk_rat

Comment: I strongly believe this answer deservers more upvotes. This feels more 'the Drupal way'. If you can solve it with configuration, then do it that way — rather then using code.

Comment: @Ideogram that's my approach, too, which is why I submitted the answer even though many of the other solutions will work. Looks like it's getting some votes ...